# Looking for Art Nouveau font close to this signwriting c. 1900 "Gatlin's Pierrots"

Tags: font-identification

Hand-written sign written c. 1900 for Gatlin's Pierrots. Similar art-nouveau style sought? Any help gratefully received for historical research into Pierrot troupes.[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling "Art Nouveau fonts"?  Where have you looked?  There are many fonts that are similar, none are exact, which is unsurprising since the sign is hand painted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it stands, there are far too many possible answers. Please add some similar fonts you have found, and why they do not qualify for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

FantasieArtistique (https://www.1001fonts.com/fantaisieartistique-font.html?text=A%20PIERROT) resembles a little bit of what you want. Although I don't think it was very good quality to be used without interventions

Other options are:
Gismonda (https://www.1001fonts.com/gismonda-fg-font.html?text=A%20PIERROT)
Cat Childs (https://www.1001fonts.com/cat-childs-font.html?text=A+PIERROT)
Teutonic (https://www.1001fonts.com/teutonic-font.html?text=A%20PIERROT)